# where is the interrupt handler of can bus driver on BeagleBone black

Tags: c, linux, interrupt, beagleboneblack, can-bus

I am trying to use the CAN bus and PRU on BBB to do some real time control, but I have checked the `$KERNEL/net/can/` and `$KERNEL/driver/net/can`, such as `af_can.c` and `raw.c` but can not find the `request_irq()`, but I do find the interrupt number 52 in `device tree` and `cat /proc/interrupts`.

I do this because that I not want the ethernet have any influence on my application.

1, Does the ethernet traffic will affect the CAN bus?

2, Where can I register my interrupt handler for the CAN bus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

though it is a year ago, I want to answer as much as I know

1. Ethernet is only affected like anything else, cause the CPU is working on the can bus.
2. If you use SocketCAN, CAN-Bus will be processed like Ethernet: by sockets. So you don't need to register an interrupt handler. Your Program will be interrupted by the socket, if you write your program right. For this search for handling sockets. There are other CAN-Bus handler, which are not used by default and shouldn't be anymore, cause they are outdated.

Comment: Thank you all the same. Now I am using epoll to handle the SocketCAN. It's pretty convenient.